# Dynamically generating a RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I might be thinking about this too deeply, but I'd still like to know if anybody has any strong opinions on it...

I'm generating a news RSS feed using PHP. Each news story has many photos, which is reflected in my database structure with a 1:many relationship between the Stories and Photos tables.  This means I'm generating a results set which looks something like:

<kbd>StoryID</kbd><kbd>PhotoID</kbd>
 
     <kbd>1</kbd>          <kbd>1</kbd>      
 
     <kbd>1</kbd>          <kbd>2</kbd>      
     <kbd>1</kbd>          <kbd>3</kbd>      
     <kbd>2</kbd>          <kbd>4</kbd>      
     <kbd>2</kbd>          <kbd>5</kbd>      
     <kbd>3</kbd>          <kbd>6</kbd>      
     <kbd>4</kbd>          <kbd>7</kbd>      
     <kbd>4</kbd>          <kbd>8</kbd>

I'm generating a nested array to represent this more accurately:

- I'm generating this just using a `foreach` statement and `if` to see if the `StoryID` already exists when dealing with each new row - is there a better way? Is there a built-in function / 3rd party library which can deal with 1:many relationships efficiently?)

There are then 3 possible options - are any of these philosophically better?:

- Modify the code so that the XML is generated without generating the array 1st
- Leave it as an array (as this seemed logical) and then use SimpleXML to rewrite it as XML (this also means that if I want to return the info as JSON, or any other format, I don't have rewrite the logic again and can just format the array) - however, is this particularly slow? Especially for a large number of RSS items?
- whichever of the above, I know some people who use PHP to write a static RSS file when the PHP is called (a new file is only generated if there is new data to be added), rather than generate the RSS file on the fly each time - are there any advantages to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm generating this just using a foreach statement and if to see if the StoryID already exists when dealing with each new row - is there a better way? Is there a built-in function / 3rd party library which can deal with 1:many relationships efficiently?)

Yes, check out Doctrine (http://doctrine-project.org/) or any other decent ORM (object-relational mapping) library.

> Modify the code so that the XML is generated without generating the array 1st

Doctrine will help with this too - not specifically generating the XML, but iterating through the database contents without necessarily having to explicitly create your array or jump through any hoops to determine relationships.

> use SimpleXML to rewrite it as XML (this also means that if I want to return the info as JSON, or any other format, I don't have rewrite the logic again and can just format the array) - however, is this particularly slow? Especially for a large number of RSS items?

This sounds like a good idea.  I've never had or heard of any performance issues with SimpleXML (although this may be a limitation of my experience) and the alternative is what, building strings yourself?  That is error-prone, hard to maintain, and probably has its own performance issues.

> use PHP to write a static RSS file when the PHP is called (a new file is only generated if there is new data to be added), rather than generate the RSS file on the fly each time - are there any advantages to this method?

It sounds like you mean caching.  What you do is, write the generated XML to a file on the web server, or to a caching service like memcached.  Then, whenever the RSS is requested, you check the timestamp on the file with another timestamp representing the time when the last change to the database was made.  If the database has been updated since the file was updated, then the file is old and needs to be re-created.

The advantage is that you can simply serve a static file after a very quick comparison of two timestamps, rather than having to generate the whole file every time.  This will mean less load on the server per request, and therefore, you can handle more simultaneous requests with the same server infrastructure.

Comment: `'the alternative is what, building strings yourself?'` - well, if I was to skip the step building the array and build the XML in the `forloop` instead then I would be writing the individual strings myself. I was hoping that SimpleXML would be optimised but I did wonder if effectively churning data through 2 different forloops would be the best way to do it.  I've always wondered what ORMs are like - maybe this is the perfect mini-project to start trying one...